# rank and the span of column matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone look over my answer for this question?

If $A$ and $B$ are conformable matrices for the product
$AB$ and if the rank of $AB$ equals the rank of $A$, then the span
of the columns of $AB$ equals the span of the columns of $A$.

Here's my answer:

Span of the columns of $AB$ equals the span of the columns of $A$ is equivalent as $Img(AB)=Img(A)$. We also know that $rank(A)=dim(Img(A))$. If $rank(A)=rank(AB)$, then $rank(A)=rank(AB)=dim(Img(AB)=dim(Img(A))$ Therefore we can conclude that if the rank of $AB$ equals the rank of $A$, then the span of the columns of $AB$ equals the span of the columns of $A$.

Does my answer makes sense?

Comment: You forgot to address the implication from equal dimension to equal subspace.

Comment: @JonathanY. I'm not sure where does this implication fit in in my answer?

Comment: In assuming $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}AB$ you've showed that $\dim\operatorname{Img}A=\dim\operatorname{Img}AB$. Now, how did you deduce that $\operatorname{Img}A=\operatorname{Img}AB$?

Comment: @JonathanY. Since $rank(A)=dim(Img(A))$ and $rank(AB)=dim(Img(AB))$ I concluded that $dim(Img(A))=rank(A)=rank(AB)=dim(Img(AB))$ Is this not sufficient enough?

Comment: $rank(A)=rank(AB)$ is given in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the main point. Indeed two subspaces can have the same dimension without being equal: think to the spans of $[0\;1]^T$ and of $[1\;0]^T$.

Hint: the image of $AB$ consists of the vectors of the form $ABv$; the image of $A$ consists of the vectors of the form $Aw$. Therefore …

Because of this, since the two subspaces have the same dimension, they are equal.

Comment: Therefore, $Bv=w$?

Comment: @Mark Yes: if you take $w=Bv$ you have that the image of $AB$ is a subset of the image of $A$, hence a subspace. But they have the same dimension, so they're equal.